# Tor transparent port appended to the urls

Tags: configuration

My problem is what if I do sniffing and later I want to extract urls/analyze with suricata, Im getitng them prepended `:9040` to all urls, but I see what it really uses tor exit node, so I want to get rid on that `:9040`

- example - `http://ipinfo.io:9040/`

I have read https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy, and it was working till a bit ago, I have the identical setup on another pc and it works there

This sound like some dnat/masquerade problem, but I have next rules:

- `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -j MASQUERADE` # I have tried add also rule as this but for input traffic, to have both
- `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i virbr0 --source 192.168.1.X -p tcp --syn ! --dport X -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040` # I have triedd change redirect to dnat --to-destination 192.168.1.1:9040, and no change, the same result
- Software

  - tor 0.3.2.9-1~xenial+1
  - ubuntu 16.04
  - iptables 1.6.0-2ubuntu3
  - ii libpcap-dev  1.7.4-2
  - un libpcap0.7-dev
  - ii  libpcap0.8:amd64 1.7.4-2
  - ii  libpcap0.8-dev   1.7.4-2
- torrc:

  - TransPort 192.168.1.1:9040
  - DNSPort 192.168.1.1:5353
- tcpdump sniffing i see connection as:

  - 192.168.1.x.49210 > 192.168.1.1.9040

Any idea what can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the transparent proxy is working as intended, this seems like a question about `iptables` and `libpcap` and how they interact with each other and not directly about Tor?

Comment: kinda is what I was thinking, but i remember on some of my tests when I set
```
TransPort 0.0.0.0:9040
DNSPort 0.0.0.0:5353
```
i had the same problem, but then i restored it and worked just fine till few days ago

Answer (score 0):

ok i have solved the problem.

it's related to docker update and change of the kernel network filter, more details here 
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?312824-Bridge-broken-after-docker-install&p=1785664#post1785664

setting them to 0 looks like solve my problem

`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
    net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
    net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0`